# sbt-proguard with play 2.2.3

Tags: playframework, sbt, proguard, playframework-2.2

We developed a web application with play 2.2.3 and want to obfuscate it. I am trying to use [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard) plugin. I put the line below to **PROJECT_FOLDER/project/plugins.sbt** file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-proguard" % "0.2.2")
```

and put the lines below to **PROJECT_FOLDER/build.sbt** file

```
proguardSettings

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard ++= Seq("-dontnote", "-dontwarn", "-ignorewarnings")

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard += ProguardOptions.keepMain("Application")

inConfig(Proguard)(javaOptions in ProguardKeys.proguard := Seq("-Xmx2g"))
```

I am not sure proguard is working when I say **dist** on play console and on the plugin website they say call **proguard:proguard**. When I write **proguard:proguard** on play console, Play gives me error shown below

```
[info] Reading program jar [/Users/kamil/DEVELOPMENT/play-2.2.3/repository/local/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.6.6/jars/ehcache-core.jar] (filtered)
[info] Reading program jar [/Users/kamil/DEVELOPMENT/play-2.2.3/repository/cache/org.json/json/jars/json-20140107.jar] (filtered)
[info] Reading library jar [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar]
[info] Reading library jar [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[error] Error: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last proguard:proguard for the full output.
[error] (proguard:proguard) Proguard failed with exit code [1]
[error] Total time: 35 s, completed 10.Tem.2014 09:45:23
```

Is there anybody using this plugin with play framework succesfully?

Answer (score 1):

After burning a few days on trying to make sbt-proguard configured properly, I gave up, and just used proguard after building the project.

Instead of including the obfuscation as a build part, I opened the zip file generated by `activator dist`, obfuscated the jar and returned it back into the lib folder with the same name. Here is how to do it:

Proguard can run on its own. You simply download the tar file from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/) and run the jar with a **configuration file** like:

```
java -jar /path/to/proguard/lib/proguard.jar @CONF_FILE
```

Now for the configuration file, You need to specify:

1. injar - the jar being obfuscated -
   After unzipping the zip file created by the dist, cd into the lib file    and found the jar names YOUR_PROJECT.VERSION-sans-externalized.jar this is the jar you need to obfuscate.
2. outjar - the path for the obfuscated jar (output). At the end of the process just copy this jar back to the lib directory and rename it to the name of the in jar.
3. keep - any package-name, class, method or field that needs to keep its name. Common things that you should keep in a webapp:

   3.1. controller method names.

   3.2. any class that is used by play and specified in the application.conf like ErrorHandler, ApplicationLoader

   3.3. All router-generated classes
4. Libraries - include all libraries in the lib file except for your own jars.

So your conf.pro file should like something like this:

```
-injars /path/to/jar/project-version-sans-externalized.jar(!META-INF)
-outjars /path/to/obfuscated/jar.jar


-keepnames class com.example.ErrorHandler
-keepnames class com.example.ApplicationLoader    

-keepnames class controllers.**
-keepclassmembernames class controllers.** {
    <methods>;    
}

-keeppackagenames controllers.**, router.**, views.**
-keep class router.** {*;}
-keepnames class router.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class router.** {*;}
-keep class views.** {*;}
-keepnames class views.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class views.** {*;}
-libraryjars /usr/lib/jvm/latest/jre/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars /path/to/lib/library1.jar
-libraryjars /path/to/lib/library2.jar
```

After obfuscation is done and you copied the output jar back to its old dir and name, you can zip back your project and you've got an obfuscated play project!

EDIT:

I really recommend looking at the [proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/). It has many examples for different project setups and frameworks.

Comment: ok @Tom but where should I put the conf.pro file? What is Its path?

Comment: @Fobi it doesn't matter

Comment: ok. @Tom, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169751/obfuscate-simple-play-2-6-x-project-with-proguard6-0-2